# How solve $\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-x)^x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I want solve $$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-x)^x}$$.

thanks for help

Comment: [No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28x^2-x%29^x)

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2-x)^x}$

$=\int(x^2-x)^{-x}~dx$

$=\int(e^{\ln(x^2-x)})^{-x}~dx$

$=\int e^{-x\ln(x^2-x)}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n(\ln(x^2-x))^n}{n!}dx$